# Has lower IQ been linked to Racism?

Tags: intelligence, race, racism

[This article](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/27/intelligence-study-links-prejudice_n_1237796.html) claims that a study links lower IQ with conservatism and racism.  It specifically claims that low IQ makes one more likely to be conservative which, in turn, makes one more likely to be prejudice.

I can not access the original study, and I don't trust a single news article to accurately sum up the article.  Have studies shown a link to low IQ and racism, and if so how significant was the link?

Comment: Duplicate is about conservatism, not racism, but is about the same study.

Comment: @Oddthinking I don't believe this is a duplicate.  I did not ask anything about conservatism, only racism.  The linked question & answer do not address racism at all.  My desire to know if racism is associated with low IQ is not answered at all by the linked question.

Comment: @dsollen the accepted answer includes "lower general intelligence (g) in childhood predicts greater racism in adulthood." That certainly does address racism.

Comment: "I did not ask anything about conservationism" - But you cite the underlying cause of the racism to be conservatism - "It specifically claims that low IQ **makes one more likely to be conservative which, in turn, makes one more likely to be prejudice**." If that was not your intent, maybe you need to edit.

Comment: This question is about the veracity of the [Bright Minds, Dark Attitudes](http://theconstitutionalistblog.com/wp-content/uploads/Dark-minds_Republican-thinking.pdf) paper. The answer to the duplicate question is about the veracity of the same study. The attacks on the methodology, the unreproducibility, the different interpretations are all applicable to your closely-related question. I did acknowledge there was a difference between conservatism and racism - they aren't equivalent.